# tableView cell Error : unable to dequeue a cell with identifier id -

Tags: ios, swift

I had a error message about my tableview cell, the message is :

unable to dequeue a cell with identifier id - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

I build this project with UIViewController, not UITableviewcontroller.  I set Cell identifier string as "Cell" and class as "Cell" on storyboard. Following is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,  UITableViewDelegate  ,  UITableViewDataSource    {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let v = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath )   as! Cell00
    
        v.img.image = UIImage(named: "0") //got error message here
    
        return v

}

@IBOutlet weak var tb: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tb.delegate = self
        self.tb.dataSource = self  
        self.tb.register(Cell00.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")
    }

}

class Cell00: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        img.image = UIImage(named: "0") //no error message, but didn't show anything
    
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
        img.image = UIImage(named: "0") //got error message here
    
    }

}
```

I don't know how to fix it, reconnect the outlet, change cell identifier string and cell class name....not working.

Comment: You mentioned `I set Cell identifier string as "Cell" and class as "Cell" on storyboard` but in your code `let v = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "id", for: indexPath )` you use the string "id". Replace "id" with "Cell"

Comment: Thank you quickly reply. I replaced it, but still get the error message .....:( in the 'cellForRowAt'.

Comment: You need to do the same change here as well `self.tb.register(Cell00.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "id")` , replace "id" with "Cell". And do you have an image named `0` in your assets ?

Comment: You should not be registering a cell class if you are using a storyboard with prototype cells

Comment: Shawn Frank: Thanks your remind, I replace it all by "Cell". And really save a Image named "0" in Assets.

Comment: Paulw11: Thank you, It's ok now! I mix the concept..

Comment: Thanks Shawn Frank's remind, if didn't replace the identifier the problem won't fix.